# how to show null resultset in postgresql or using some sql query skill

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

suppose I have a sql like this:

```
select * from tba
```

if table tba have data, it will be shown like below:

```
id    name    num
1     tom     100
2     jack    200
```

now i need query tba by where conditon

```
select num from tba where id = 3;
```

here is the question: there's no data anymore by this sql, will be like this:

```
id    name    num
//no data, just have column name
```

so, i want to it tell me that there's no result or only zero, like:

```
num
0
```

how can i get the result?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(num), 0) AS num
FROM   tba
WHERE  id = 3
```

---

If you wanted to select all columns, you can do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0)       AS id,
       COALESCE(MAX(name), 'N/A') AS name,
       COALESCE(MAX(num), 0)      AS num
FROM   tba
WHERE  id = 3;
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8f171/9/1)

Comment: wow, very good ! I am trying to select all columns and using the same way . Thanks Zane

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(num,0) AS num
  FROM tba
 WHERE id = 3
```

Comment: 1) `ISNULL` is not supported by PostgreSQL. 2) `ISNULL` in MySQL returns only either 0 or 1. 3) Without wrapping the `num` column in an aggregate function, you would return no results even if you made a conditional check on it.

Comment: My fault, did not pay attention to the postgresql tag.

Comment: @Yaroslav , your answer is also very helpful for me :)